# Can I create 10VAC from 12VDC?

Tags: power-supply

I've got a 12VDC input thats being used to create 5V to run a AVR and 8V to run 8DC motors. I need 10VAC as well to run some accessories. Basically they are just [switches](http://thumbs.picclick.com/00/s/OTAwWDE2MDA=/z/q1gAAOSwcLxYKbYh/$/z-gauge-job-lot-points-electric-manual-_57.jpg) controlled with a solenoid. So the draw on the 10VAC will be minimal.

Comment: Yes you can. Look into inverters.

Comment: (1) Have you opened one of these switches?  What's inside of it?  Are you sure that you need AC?  If there is a rectifier, then there is a chance that DC could work.  (2) Solenoids are current-controlled In my experience, "*solenoid*" usually doesn't spell "*current draw will be minimal [as minimal comes]*".  Then again, it could be a very small solenoid.

Comment: Pretty sure you could just use an H-bridge to drive it from 12V. By tweaking the high and low times you could approximate 10V of AC. As Jasen says in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you could produce an approximation of 10V AC from your 12V input if you can drive an H-bridge with the right timings.

see "modified sine wave"

Answer (score 0):

It can be done.  There are two divergent paths -- the first:  If you have plenty of excess 12V capacity (more than a few amperes worth), you could simply buy a small inverter at an auto jobber, and power a garden variety Märklin compatible accessory transformer.  This will be horribly inefficient, but requires no designing or construction.

The second, much more complex path, would be to design a custom inverter.

Something that would take 12V and regulate it down to 10V, and feed that into a transistor array called an "H-Bridge" to generate 10Vrms (more or less) AC.

Comment: Adding a separate inverter to pre-regulate the 12V down to 10V prior to the H-bridge seems like an un-necessary step.  I built a 600W sine-wave generator and I just used a 40kHz PWM and an LC post filter to make a nice smooth sinewave of any amplitude less than the supply.